# Compare start and end time in 24 hour format without zeroes?

Tags: jquery

I have two input fields, one start and one end time. They are both in 24 hour format and is displayed this way:
Start time: `01:10` End Time: `23:04` but if I inspect the input I can see that the value is really saved as this: Start time: `1:10` and End time: `23:4`.

I want to compare these two times, and if they are identical, give a warning, and if the start time is greater than the end time give another warning.
This is where I am at:

```
$('#publish').click(function()  {
    var quantityI =  parseInt($('#time_from').val());
    var quantity = parseInt($('#time_to').val());
    /* If start time is greater then end time, show alert */
    if( quantityI > quantity) {
        $('#alert_slide_start_end_time').modal({
        });
        return false;
    }
    /* If start time and end time is identical, show alert */
    else if( quantityI = quantity) {
        $('#alert_slide_start_end_time_identical').modal({
        });
        return false;
    }
    else {
    }
});
```

The problem is that the compare I am doing doesn't seem to work with the format? Is it possible to convert the time into epoch and then compare it? Or what is the best approach?

EDIT: Solution here: [Compare start time amd end time with jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11244943/compare-start-time-amd-end-time-with-jquery)

Comment: Can you also share the html code so we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: This question is already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11244943/compare-start-time-amd-end-time-with-jquery

Comment: @ameya thank you! Sorry, I did not find that!